# Display rows from database filtered by year/month/week asp.net core mvc by input

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im currently working on a sales report function. I want to generate a sales report by input of year/month/week. In my DAL class you can see that I wrote a query which shows all the sales from 2020. I have hardcoded this in the query but I want to display the sales by input. Look at the image below for explanation. The user has to choose by input the month and/or year to display. English is not my native language sorry for that.

[This is an image of my Index view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS76E.png)

This is my DAL, I currently hardcoded the  '01/01/2020' AND OrderDatum < '01/01/2021' for testing purposes.

```
public List<OrderModel> getByYear()
    {
        List<OrderModel> Orderlist = new List<OrderModel>();
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Order] WHERE OrderDatum >= '01/01/2020' AND OrderDatum < '01/01/2021';";

            DataSet results = ExecuteSql(sql, new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());

            for (int x = 0; x < results.Tables[0].Rows.Count; x++)
            {
                OrderModel c = DatasetParser.DataSetToSpeler(results, x);
                Orderlist.Add(c);
            }
            return Orderlist;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

This is my OrderModel

```
 public class OrderModel
{
    public int BestellingId { get; set; }
    public int KlantID { get;  set; }
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
    public double Totaalprijs { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<ProductModel> Producten { get; set; }

    public OrderModel(int bestellingId, int klantId, DateTime datum, double totaalPrijs, string status)
    {
        BestellingId = bestellingId;
        KlantID = klantId;
        Datum = datum;
        Totaalprijs = totaalPrijs;
        Status = status;
    }

    public OrderModel()
    {

    }
}
```

The only function I use in my controller.

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<OrderModel> orders = rapport.getByYear();
        return View(orders);
    }
```

My Index view

```
@model List<OrderModel>;

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
</div>

<div>
<table class="table" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
    <thead style="color: darkred;">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>KlantId</th>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>TotaalPrijs</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="">
        @foreach (OrderModel order in Model) { 
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.BestellingId)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.KlantID)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.Datum)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.Status)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.Totaalprijs)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Pass startdate and enddate from view to controller ,and change string sql to `string sql = $"SELECT * FROM [Order] WHERE OrderDatum >= {startdate} AND OrderDatum < {enddate};";`

Comment: Thankyou Im going to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a dynamic query as

```
public static string GetQuery(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    string query = @"select * from table
                    where dateCol > '" + startDate + @"' and dateCol < '" + endDate + @"'";

    return query;
}
```